# Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at file:///android_asset/www/js/DB.js

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, web-sql, cordova-3

I m using cordova to build hybrid android app and i m using this function which return database object its works fine everywhere in app

```
    function openDB() {
        var dbUser = null;
        var dBVersion = localStorage.getItem("db_version");
        if (dBVersion == null) {
            try {
                if (!window.openDatabase) {
                    console.log('db init failed');
                } else {
                    dbUser = window.openDatabase("dbname", "1.0.1", "local", 100000);

                }
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(e);
                if (e.name == "INVALID_STATE_ERR") {
                    console.log("Invalid database version.");
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");
                }
            }
        } else {
            dbUser = window.openDatabase("dbname", dBVersion, "local", 100000);
        }
        console.log(dbUser);
        //initialize tables
        if (dbUser != null)
            createTables(dbUser);
        return dbUser;
    }
```

but when i use social plugin like facebook and foursquare and return to app then my app wont able to access the database and give error

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at file:///android_asset/www/js/DB.js:27 
dbUser = window.openDatabase("dbname", dBVersion, "local", 100000);
```

and the my app become blank as its wont able to access the database.

Comment: are you using inAppBrowser plugin to go to facebook / foursquare??

Comment: no ,i m using cordova plugin for facebook and once i login and share some data i wont able to access the database and got this error

Answer (score 0):

When do you execute your code?

If you check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070042/security-err-dom-exception-18-opendatabase-using-phonegap) you should only execute Database queries after your device is ready. So wait for the `deviceready` event triggered from cordova.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", openDB, false);
```

Note, that this will only be triggered on the phone, not on the browser anymore.

I think for older cordova versions there was as well a limit of the database size. `100000` seems to be quite random, isn't it?

Hope this helps.